# Unable to use the "embed PDF & EPS files (experimental)" option on Scribus 1.4.5 Mac

Tags: macos, pdf, export, scribus

I cannot use the option, marked experimental, saying "embed PDF & EPS files (experimental)" on Scribus (1.4.5), Macintosh OS X 10.6.8.
When I go to the "export" section, this option appears in grey, and is not clickable.

Is it related to Scribus (1.4.5) on Macintosh, or should I do something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's related to Scribus 1.4.5 on OS X and cannot be fixed.

The developer that creates the .dmg seens not to be able to compile Podofo for the 1.4 series anymore.

https://bugs.scribus.net/view.php?id=13068

As a workaround you can download a Scribus 1.4.4 and create your PDFs with it.
You can share your .sla Scribus file between the two versions and install them side by side (just use a different name like "Scribus 1.4.4" instead of "Scribus" for the older version).
Just take care not to open the file with the both versions at the same time.

Two further remarks:

- The next stable release 1.6 is not affected by this problem.
- Be very careful when using this experimental feature: the resulting PDF might look fine on screen but not correct process for the print shop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which proved to be very efficient. I did produce a PDF which looks fine. I'll try to check at the print shop!